# How send Email from server email in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I am new **laravel** and i just made a small project of article posting and on user registration i just want to send successfully register email to user email. I searched every where in all tutorials they are giving demo for send mail from gmail and some another email providers. I just want to know is it possible to send the mail simply from server email id ? like **cordignator** framework:

```
$this->email->to('rahul@gmail.com')
$this->email->subject('Testing Email')
$this->email->message('hello')
$this->email->send()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your server mail details in .env file then
run a command `php artisan publish`

send mail like `Mail::to($user)->send(new UserRegister());`

and your UserRegister class in app/Mail have one method

```
public function build()
{

    return $this->subject("Welcome to My site")
            ->view('`vendor.notifications.register`',compact(''));
}
```

And You can set all message body in `resourse/view/vendor/notifications/register`

see more on [laravel mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail)

Comment: ok..means i do not need to add any smtp details in `.env` file?

Comment: oh sorry you have to add your mail detail in .env file also

Comment: which email details in need to put there ?? in simple php we just use mail function `to`,`subject`,`message`

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=<your mail host>
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=<your mail address>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<your password>

Comment: you means server email id: `info@domain.com` ?

Comment: yea sure your domain mail id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139547/discussion-between-dharmendra-singh-and-rahul-sharma).